# Toolbar content description didn't work as expected

Tags: android, talkback, accessibility

I am setting `contentDescription` to a toolbar in Fragment and DialogFragment class.

In `Fragment` class, It works fine.
(e.g.

1. on toolbar focused,`"toolbarContentDescription"`
2. on next swipe forward, `"Navigation Up"`
3. on next swipe backward, "toolbarContentDescription")

In `DialogFragment` class, It reads navigation up first.
(e.g.

1. on toolbar focused, `"Navigation Up toolbarContentDescription"`
2. on next swipe forward, `"Navigation Up"`
3. on next swipe backward, `"toolbarContentDescription"`)

I am using the same code to set toolbar in both classes.

I tried to fix it by changing the position of `navigationContentDescription`. But it didn't work in dialogFragment class. and If I remove navigationContentDescription, on the back arrow it will read `"Unlabeled Botton"`.

```
fun setToolBar(toolbar: Toolbar, title: String) {
    getMainActivity().setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    toolbar.title = title
    toolbar.contentDescription = "toolbar content description here"
    toolbar.setTitleTextAppearance(context, R.style.white_toolbar_text)
    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white))

    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_back_arrow)
    // set back arrow content description.
    toolbar.navigationContentDescription  = "Navigation Up"
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
                getMainActivity().onBackPressed()
        }

    toolbar.requestFocus()
toolbar.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED)
}
```

I don't understand the reason for this different behavior. It should read the same toolbar description as a fragment class in dialog fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TalkBack` has a special treat to `Dialog` screens. In every dialog, the screen reader makes a special announcement of its title. I don't think you will be able to change this behavior, since it is not in your app scope, but in the `TalkBack` implementation itself.

Answer (score 2):

We can get title view and set contentDescription to that view. Here I have screen title is "Dashboard" and announcing as "Dashboard Heading"

```
toolbar.forEachIndexed { index, view ->
            if (view is TextView && view.text == "Dashboard") {
                view.contentDescription = "Dashboard Heading"
                return@forEachIndexed
            }
        }
```

Comment: I had an issue where the toolbar.navigationContentDescription disabled the navigation on a dialogFragment.  This solution fixed it.